# Retorno via Ajax data em um input type date com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho o seguinte código Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
        url:"../connect/post/infoTask.php",
        data:'info-task='+idtask,               
        success:function(responseData){                     
                $(".delivery-info").val(responseData.Delivery);         
        }    
});
```

Retorno Json para o Ajax:

```
$selInfoTasks= new Tasks();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $idTask = $_POST['info-task'];  
    $stInfoTasks = $selInfoTasks->selectInfoTask($idTask);

    echo json_encode($stInfoTasks);

    exit();
}
```

Via o Id da Tarefa ele busca várias informações, neste caso coloquei apenas o **Delivery**, que é o que me interessa.

Eu retorno o **Delivery** que é um campo *DATE* no banco:

```
public function selectInfoTask($idTask){

        try {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Tasks.*, 
                                              DATE_FORMAT( tasks.Delivery , '%d/%m/%Y' ) 
                                              AS Delivery 
                                              FROM Tasks 
                                              WHERE TasksId = $idTask");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }catch (PDOException $exception){
                        header("Location: ./error.php?err=Unable-to-find-info");
                        echo 'Error: '.$excption->getMessage();
                        return null;
                }

        }
}
```

No SELECT já coloco no formato que desejo.

Mas quando mando este para o campo:

```
<label>Entrega</label>
    <div class="input-group">                                                                           
            <input id="delivery-info" type="date" class="form-control task-viewer delivery-info" disabled>
    <span class="input-group-btn"> 

<span class="btn"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</span>                                                                                                                 
</div>
```

Código que retorna a consulta para o javascript:

```
$selInfoTasks= new Tasks();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ $idTask = $_POST['info-task'];
    $stInfoTasks = $selInfoTasks->selectInfoTask($idTask);
    echo json_encode($stInfoTasks);
    exit();
}
```

Ele não preenche com a data, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Onde vc retorna o json ou texto para o javascript?

Comment: @rray `$selInfoTasks= new Tasks();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $idTask = $_POST['info-task']; 
 $stInfoTasks = $selInfoTasks->selectInfoTask($idTask);

 echo json_encode($stInfoTasks);

 exit();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou transformar o texto enviado pelo PHP em um json válido, `responseData.Delivery` não faz nada.

Mude:

```
$(".delivery-info").val(responseData.Delivery);
```

Para:

```
var res = JSON.parse(responseData);
$(".delivery-info").val(res.Delivery);
```

Comment: Não está indo, estava lendo uma documentação aqui sobre o campo date no input, e vou ter que deixar como text o type mesmo.